# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' en mi codigo en python

Tags: python

he estado buscando la respuesta a mi pregunta pero no entiendo muy bien.
Estoy haciendo una calculadora con input() y me sale

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

aqui mi codigo

```
    multiplicar = "m"
respuesta = input()

if respuesta == multiplicar:
    print("Has seleccionado multiplicar")
    print("Escribe el primer numero.")
    a = input()
    print("escribe el segundo numero.")
    b = input()
    c = a * b
    print("la multiplicacion de esos 2 numeros dan:")
    print(c)
else:
    print("code not working")
```

diganme si tengo que cambiar algo,soy nuevo en stackoverflow

Comment: Estás intentando multiplicar dos strings. La función [`input()`](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-entrada-teclado.html) retorna un string, por lo que para poder multiplicar los valores deberías considerar hacer un casteo a entero con [`int()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_int.asp), eso asumiento que solo funcionará con enteros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenidx Fainty! c:

## Explicación

Python no es adivino, no puede saber mágicamente que lo que escribe el usuario es un numero. Por lo que la función input siempre devolverá una cadena. Es decir, que Python piensa que los números que estás ingresando en tu calculadora son palabras o frases. Y precisamente por eso trata los números como dichas.

Si en Python intentas hacer la cuenta "1"*"2" saldrá exactamente el mismo error. Por que? por que no se puede multiplicar una palabra por otra palabra.

## Solución

Una cosa que se puede hacer al respecto es asumir que el usuario va a ingresar algo que se puede convertir a número.

Cambia esta linea `a = input()` por esta `a = int(input())`. Ese comando int adicional hace que lo devuelto por input (que es una cadena) se transforme en un numero. Aplica el mismo principio en la linea `b = input()` y tu problema estará solucionado c:

Si el usuario escribe en la calculadora algo que no puede ser pensado como numero (ej: ac12) Python generará un error.